# polymorphic_path or url_for how customize controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I have @challenge and @idea instances from Challenge and Idea model responsively.

I have one partial which is going to used in many controllers, so based on controllers I want to generate path.

e.g 
So when I am in IdeasController polymorphic_path([@challenge, @idea]) will generate "/challenges/12/ideas/45"

but if I am in any other controller suppose RefinementsController, I want generate path as "challenges/12/refinements/45"

How can I generate it using polymorphic_path or url_for

code:

*app/controllers/ideas_controller.rb*

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :challenge
  load_and_authorize_resource :idea, through: :challenge

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

*app/controllers/refinements_controller.rb*

```
class RefinementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :challenge, parent: true
  load_and_authorize_resource :idea, through: :challenge, parent: false

  def index
    @ideas = @ideas.refined
    render 'ideas/index'
  end

  def show
    render 'ideas/show'
  end
end
```

*app/views/ideas/index.html.erb*

```
<div class="ideas">
  <% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <div class="idea">
      <div class="title">
        <%= link_to idea.title, polymorphic_path([@challenge, idea]) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

*app/views/ideas/show.html.erb*

```
<div class="idea">
  <div class="title">
    <%= link_to idea.title, polymorphic_path([@challenge, @idea]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="descriptio">
    <%= @idea.description %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: rest of code in a form will be same?

Comment: So basically I don't have form except only index and show action. In IdeasController user will see 'X' number of ideas listing and out of 'X', 'Y' will be selected and shown under RefinementsController. Except show url of idea instance nothing is changing.
i.e "/challenges/3/ideas/12" in IdeasController 
    "/challenges/3/refinements/12" in RefinementsController

Comment: @RahulChaudhari did you try my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

*Although it's not a good practice but if it's only a minor change and rest of your partial is same in all cases then what you do is **use some generic variable in your partial. In your case your polymorphic url depends on the initialized value of second variable i.e @idea(as first part challenges/12/ is same)*** so you can do something like this:

```
polymorphic_path([@challenge,@something_generic])
```

and now depending on your controllers action you can change `@something_generic` to make proper url for your form

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
    @something_generic = @challenge.ideas.build
  end
end

class RefinementsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
    @something_generic = @challenge.refinements.build
  end
end
```

**Update:**

Change your code to this:

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :challenge
  load_and_authorize_resource :idea, through: :challenge

  def index
  end

  def show
    @something_generic = Idea.find(params[:id])
  end
end

class RefinementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :challenge, parent: true
  load_and_authorize_resource :idea, through: :challenge, parent: false

  def index
    @something_generic = Refinement.find(params[:id])
    render 'ideas/index'
  end

  def show
    @something_generic = Refinement.find(params[:id])
    render 'ideas/show'
  end
end
```

Since you are using cancancan and have proper filters so @idea and @challenge will be defined automatically in your actions.

**For index.html i think you'll be better of using separate templates** but if you still want to use a single template then you can do something like this:

app/views/ideas/index.html.erb

```
<div class="ideas">
  <% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <div class="idea">
      <div class="title">
        <% if controller_name == "ideas" %>
          <%= link_to idea.title, polymorphic_path([@challenge, idea]) %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to idea.title, polymorphic_path([@challenge, @something_generic]) %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and show.html.erb

```
<div class="idea">
  <div class="title">
    <%= link_to @idea.title, polymorphic_path([@challenge, @something_generic]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
      <%= @idea.description %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Issue is in Refinementscontroller also I have to use @idea object. Since suppose if you have 10 ideas in IdeasController index page, then only 3 will be selected and will be available in RefinementsController. So when index partial is rendered using idea controller is should provide show page using idea controller i.e
"/challenges/1/ideas/10" which is happening. But when RefinementsController rendering same index page it should render "/challenges/1/refinements/10"

Comment: @RahulChaudhari once you are inside refinement controller you can simply change `@something_generic` to contain your refinement and use your @challenge variable to find your ideas selected

Comment: Clicked wrong link! No problem - I just wanted to make it right

Comment: Email sent with an apology

Comment: @something_generic is object of idea, so by default polymorphic_path will call model_name on it, and it will return "ideas/12" as string which will be get appended to "/challenges/1/"

Comment: @RahulChaudhari my bad didn't notice that. Updated my answer for you. I have made changes in both controller and templates

Answer (score 0):

**Partial**

Without having your `partial` code here, I'm going to make an assumption that you are calling `polymorphic_path` inside your partial, hence wanting to change the path as per the controller it's loaded from

If you're calling a partial, you have to remember its been designed to be an independent, [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) element of your application, and so including `@instance variables` in your partial will likely be an [antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

What I would recommend is to populate your partial with [`local` variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), allowing you to populate those accordingly:

```
#app/controllers/ideas_controller.rb
Class IdeasController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @challenge = Challenge.find params[:challenge_id] if params[:challenge_id].present?
       @idea = Idea.find params[:id]
    end
end

#app/views/ideas/show.html.erb
<%= render "shared/partial", locals: {challenge: @challenge, child: @idea} %>

#app/views/shared/_partial.html.erb
<%= link_to "Test", polymorphic_path([challenge, child]) %>
```

--

**Update**

Thanks for your code

You'll be totally better be using the following:

```
#app/views/ideas/index.html.erb
<%= render "ideas/item", collection: @items, as: :item, locals: {challenge: @challenge} %>

#app/views/ideas/show.html.erb
<%= render "ideas/item", object: @item, as: :item, locals: {challenge: @challenge} %>
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/views/ideas/_idea.html.erb
<div class="idea">
  <div class="title">
    <%= link_to idea.title, polymorphic_path([challenge, idea]) %>
  </div>
  <% if action_name =="show" %>
    <div class="descriptio">
      <%= idea.description %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: In above answer _idea partial should be written as _item and should refer item local variable, correct?

Comment: It is not working and it should be. Since polymorphic_path calls model_name on idea(item) object. So in both controller, it returns path as "/challenges/12/ideas/34"

Comment: Okay. You posted two views for `ideas` - how am I meant to know how you populate the `refinements` controller view? Can you post your refinement controller views please.

Comment: If you check refinement controller's code, you will fins that I am using ideas controller's views